# SQLAlchemy place subqueries side by side instead of nesting

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a query that includes two subqueries. In SQL it looks roughly like this:

```
SELECT sq2.foo,
       sq2.bar
FROM (
      SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE foo = '123'
) AS sq1,
LATERAL (
      SELECT foo, bar FROM bar WHERE s1.foo = 'zomething'
) AS sq2
WHERE sq2.foo = 'something';
```

This is what I need from SQLAlchemy. When I translate it to Alchemy, I get roughly this:

```
sq1 = session.query(Bar.foo).filter(Bar.foo == '123').subquery()
sq2 = session.query(Bar.foo).filter(sq1.foo == 'zomething').subquery().lateral()
session.query(sq2.foo, sq2.bar).filter(sq.foo = 'something').all()
```

However, this does not translate to the same as the top SQL but rather nests the queries like this:

```
SELECT sq2.foo,
       sq2.bar
FROM LATERAL (
    SELECT foo, bar FROM (
        SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE foo = '123'
    ) AS sq1,
    bar
    WHERE sq1.foo = 'zomething'
) AS sq2
WHERE sq2.foo = 'something';
```

This doesn't yield the same result for reasons that are probably too complicated to explain based on this simplified example. SQLAlchemy does however do the right thing, if I change the final query to include something from `sq1` that I don't really need, like this:

```
session.query(sq2.foo, sq2.bar, sq1.foo).filter(sq.foo = 'something').all()
```

Now it returns the query with the right structure. Is there a way to force subqueries side-by-side without including worthless data?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [select_from](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html?highlight=select_from#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.select_from)

```
sq1 = session.query(Bar.foo).filter(Bar.foo == '123').subquery().alias('sq1')
sq2 = session.query(Bar.foo, Bar.bar).filter(sq1.c.foo == 'zomething').subquery().lateral('sq2')
q = session.query(sq2.c.foo, sq2.c.bar).select_from(sq1, sq2).filter(sq2.c.foo == 'something')

# >> print(q)
# SELECT sq2.foo AS sq2_foo, sq2.bar AS sq2_bar 
# FROM LATERAL (SELECT bar.foo AS foo, bar.bar AS bar 
# FROM bar 
# WHERE sq1.foo = %(foo_1)s) AS sq2, (SELECT bar.foo AS foo 
# FROM bar 
# WHERE bar.foo = %(foo_2)s) AS sq1
# WHERE sq2.foo = %(foo_3)s
```

Comment: This is closer to the correct query, BUT this orders the subqueries incorrectly so the lateral sq2 comes before sq1 in SQL and it then you get the `missing FROM-clause entry for table "anon_2"` thing. Changing the order of the subqueries in `select_from` does not change anything. If I take the produced SQL from Alchemy and change the order of the subqueries manually, then it works. Any way to combat this? Or is this a bug in Alchemy?

Comment: With `session.query(sq1.c.foo, sq2.c.foo, sq2.c.bar)` it generates from-clauses in the right order. I don't know how to explicitly set this order.

Comment: Yup, that's what I encountered too. Thanks for the effort though!